# DateTimePicker not using custom format string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetimepicker, cultureinfo

I am using a [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) `DateTimePicker` control with a custom formatting applied to it:

```
this.dateTimePicker.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
this.dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm";
this.dateTimePicker.RightToLeftLayout = false;
```

On my machine this works OK, but on a specific user's machine the date is not being printed according to this custom format.

Instead, it seems like the date is printed in reverse, something like:

```
"35:10 2013/05/23"
```

I could not find any information on the net why this occurs.

Comment: does that user have any specific language/locale settings set in control panel ?

Comment: Yes, he does, but replicating that setting on my environment didn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Can you share those settings ?

Comment: I will once i have access to that machine. The settings shouldn't matter in case i provide a custom format.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft)
{
    this.dateTimePicker.RightToLeftLayout = true;
}
else
{
    this.dateTimePicker.RightToLeftLayout = false;
}
```